# Parsing HTML span with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to figure out how to use Beautiful Soup and am having a hard time.

My HTML page has several elements that look like this:

```
<a class="propertyName" href="/preferredguest/property/overview/index.html?propertyID=1023"><span>The Westin Peachtree Plaza, Atlanta
</span></a>

<a class="propertyName" href="/preferredguest/property/overview/index.html?propertyID=1144"><span>Sheraton Atlanta Hotel
</span></a>
```

I'm trying to create an array with the hotel names. Here is my code so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "removed"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)

hotels = soup.find_all('a', class_="propertyName")
```

But I cannot figure out how to iterate over the hotels array to display the span element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "hotel" name are inside a `span`. One way is using the [`.select()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) method

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''<a class="propertyName" href="/preferredguest/property/overview/index.html?propertyID=1023"><span>The Westin Peachtree Plaza, Atlanta
... </span></a>
... 
... <a class="propertyName" href="/preferredguest/property/overview/index.html?propertyID=1144"><span>Sheraton Atlanta Hotel
... </span></a>
... ''', 'lxml')
>>> [element.get_text(strip=True) for element in soup.select('a.propertyName > span')]
['The Westin Peachtree Plaza, Atlanta', 'Sheraton Atlanta Hotel']
>>>
```

or

```
>>> names = []
>>> for el in hotels:
...     names.append(el.find('span').get_text(strip=True))
... 
>>> names
['The Westin Peachtree Plaza, Atlanta', 'Sheraton Atlanta Hotel']
>>>
```